# document.scripts returning undefined in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I an trying to debug why a script isn't working in firefox but is in other programs. Part of the excellent [chirp.js](http://lab.rog.ie/chirp/) has the line:

```
script = document.scripts[document.scripts.length-1]
```

Which throws the error: **document.scripts is undefined**

So I run document.scripts in the firebug console and it returns undefined, as you would expect, so I head over to Mozilla and see if it's called something else and it's [listed there](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.scripts) as being accessible. I type the same thing into the Chrome console and I get a list of scripts loaded.

This happens on my machine and my client's too, so I'm guessing it's not a plugin/addon issue?

I get the same error on the chirp project page.

Anyone come across this issue before? I tried googling, but get pages of results relating to the document.scripts object and no problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something else isn't right here.  Even writing the following will give you a length of 1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>alert(document.scripts.length);</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Try that in your Firefox installation. If that works then something else is wrong.

Note: I tested it in the latest version of Firefox for Mac as of 1/23/13.

Comment: It looks like I was running a very old version of Firefox (I develop in Chrome and haven't had a problem before when I check in Firefox). I got the client to update their software, and it works for them too now!